# Binding custom properties in style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have a custom Template for the DataGridColumnHeader.

[image]

My code (data grid):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ReportDG"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=SourceData, Mode=TwoWay}"
              Style="{StaticResource ReportGridStyle}"
              Height="500"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              HeadersVisibility="Column"
              Sorting="ReportDG_Sorting">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding FIO, Mode=OneWay}" HeaderStringFormat="FIO"/>
...
```

My code (style):

```
<!-- DataGridColumnHeader style -->
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" x:Key="ReportColumnHeaderStyle" >
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Border x:Name="BackgroundBorder"
                                BorderThickness="0, 0, 0, 2"
                                Background="White"
                                BorderBrush="LightGray"
                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

                        <controls:TextBoxWithPlaceholder 
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    Style="{StaticResource FilterTextBoxStyle}"
                                    Placeholder="Filter by name"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Margin="4 2 4 2"/>

                        <ContentPresenter Margin="6, 0, 12, 0"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          Grid.Row="1"
                                          Grid.Column="0"/>

                        <Path x:Name="SortArrow" 
                              Visibility="Collapsed" 
                              Data="M11.29,11.46a1,1,0,0,0,1.42,0l3-3A1,1,0,1,0,14.29,7L12,9.34,9.71,7A1,1,0,1,0,8.29,8.46Zm3,1.08L12,14.84l-2.29-2.3A1,1,0,0,0,8.29,14l3,3a1,1,0,0,0,1.42,0l3-3a1,1,0,0,0-1.42-1.42Z" 
                              Stretch="Fill"
                              Grid.Column="1" 
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              Width="12" 
                              Height="14" 
                              Fill="LightGray" 
                              Margin="0,0,8,0"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"/>
            ...
```

I need to set binding between "Filter by name" textbox and some ViewModel field.

Also it would be good to set placeholder (for example "Filter by name") as DataGridTextColumn Property.

How I can do it?

Comment: I don't think it's a very good idea to bind between a control template and the control's data context because it ties you to using that control with only one type of View-Model  But if you must, then you should use TemplateBinding to bind the `Text` property because you are in a `ControlTemplate`.  Something like this `Text="{TemplateBinding DataContext.SomeTextProperty}"`  Alternately you could bind with `FindAncestor`  e.g.  `Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.SomeTextProperty}"`

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the `TextBox` to a property of a parent element in the visual tree using the `RelativeSource` property of the binding:

```
<controls:TextBoxWithPlaceholder ...
    Text="{Binding DataContext.ViewModelProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
```

> Also it would be good to set placeholder (for example "Filter by name") as DataGridTextColumn Property. How I can do it?

You can bind to a property of the parent column using the `Column` property of the `DataGridColumnHeader`. The question is *what* property of the column to bind to. You may want to define a custom [attached property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/attached-properties-overview?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

Comment: I need to implement search textbox for each column. So I need to bind each column to own View Model property

Comment: Then you need an individual template for each column. There is no way to reuse a template and just replace the binding path in XAML.